# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host and window.location.host uppercase

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iis

Strange question, i know, but, in any case, can `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` or `window.location.host` return value in uppercase? Should i use `.toLowercase` and `.ToLower` to be sure that all will be ok?

Answer (score 0):

Using the ToLower() would work as it is a string value however what effect would it have on a host address? It will still just show as 192.xxx.xxx if you get my point

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
```

Comment: It returns something like "sitename.com" in our case. We need to be sure, that in one moment it will not return "siTeNamE.com". Same with JS window.location.host.